# How to decrease memory usage in a for loop in R

Tags: r, memory

I am creating a panel data frame. It is a panel of schools. To this panel I want to merge the first closest weather station, then the second, third, etc until the 10th closest one. I wrote a loop that does this for different variables: maximum temperature, minimum temperature, precipitation, etc. The issue that I am having is that it seems that I am unnecessarily allocating memory somewhere inside this loop since I run out of memory.

I know I have enough memory to create the panel since I did it once already without the loop. I am working on windows on 64 bit with 8gb of RAM. I have a sample of 7800 schools, and 800 weather stations for the 2010-2015 period.

This is a reproducible example with only 5 schools, 10 weather stations and 2 months of data and matching only the 3 closest stations. The real example is 7800 schools, 800 weather stations, 5 years of data and matching the 10 closest stations.

```
library(data.table)
Dist_Temp_Max<-data.frame(ID_School=seq(1:5),ID_Station_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),
                          ID_Station_2=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_2=floor(runif(5, min=11, max=100)),
                          ID_Station_3=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_3=floor(runif(5, min=101, max=200)))
Dist_Temp_Min<-data.frame(ID_School=seq(1:5),ID_Station_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),
                          ID_Station_2=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_2=floor(runif(5, min=11, max=100)),
                          ID_Station_3=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_3=floor(runif(5, min=101, max=200)))
Dist_Prec<-data.frame(ID_School=seq(1:5),ID_Station_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),
                      ID_Station_2=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_2=floor(runif(5, min=11, max=100)),
                      ID_Station_3=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_3=floor(runif(5, min=101, max=200)))

years<-seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"),as.Date("2015-02-28"),by="1 day")
Weather_Data<-data.frame(ID_School=seq(1:5))
Weather_Data<-expand.grid(Weather_Data$ID_School,years)
names(Weather_Data)<-c("ID_Station","Date")
Weather_Data$Temp_Max_T<-runif(nrow(Weather_Data), min=10, max=40)
Weather_Data$Temp_Min_T<-Weather_Data$Temp_Max-10
Weather_Data$Prec_T<-floor(runif(nrow(Weather_Data),min=0, max=10))
Weather_Data$Cod_Merge<-paste(Weather_Data$ID_Station,Weather_Data$Date,sep="-")

#Add Values per Station
var_list<-c("Temp_Max","Temp_Min","Prec")
for (i in var_list) {
  dist<-paste0("Dist_",i)
  dist<-get(dist)
  dist<-as.data.frame(subset(dist,!is.na(dist$ID_Station_1)))
  matr<-dist[c("ID_School","ID_Station_1","Dist_1")]
  matr<-setDT(matr)[, list(Date=years,ID_Station_1=ID_Station_1,Dist_1=Dist_1) , ID_School]
 
  matr$Cod_Merge<-paste(matr$ID_Station_1,matr$Date,sep="-")
  matr<-as.data.frame(matr[,c("Cod_Merge","ID_School","Date","ID_Station_1","Dist_1")])
  matr<-merge(matr,Weather_Data[c("Cod_Merge",paste0(i,"_T"))],by="Cod_Merge",all.x=T)
  matr$Cod_Merge<-paste(matr$ID_School,matr$Date,sep="-")
  names(matr)[6]<-paste0(i,"_T_1")
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  print(i)
 
  for(n in 2:3) {
    matr2<-dist[c("ID_School",paste0("ID_Station_",n),paste0("Dist_",n))]
    matr2<-subset(dist,!is.na(dist[paste0("ID_Station_",n)]))
    matr3<-expand.grid(matr2$ID_School,years)

    names(matr3)<-c("ID_School","Date")
    matr3<-matr3[order(matr3$ID_School,matr3$Date), ]
    matr2<-merge(matr3,matr2,by="ID_School")
    rm(matr3)
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    print(i)
    
    matr2$Cod_Merge<-paste(matr2[,paste0("ID_Station_",n)],matr2$Date,sep="-")
    matr2<-matr2[c("Cod_Merge","ID_School","Date",paste0("ID_Station_",n),paste0("Dist_",n))]
    matr2<-merge(matr2,Weather_Data[,c("Cod_Merge",paste0(i,"_T"))],by="Cod_Merge",all.x=T)
    matr2$Cod_Merge<-paste(matr2$ID_School,matr2$Date,sep="-")
    
    names(matr2)[6]<-paste0(i,"_T_",n)
    matr<-merge(matr,matr2[,c("Cod_Merge",
                              paste0("ID_Station_",n),
                              paste0("Dist_",n),
                              paste0(i,"_T_",n))],
                by="Cod_Merge",all.x=T)
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    print(i)
  }
  assign(paste0("Mat_Dist_",i),matr)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Solution

For anyone who is interested, I was missing a couple of commas inside the 2nd loop:

```
library(data.table)
Dist_Temp_Max<-data.frame(ID_School=seq(1:5),ID_Station_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),
                          ID_Station_2=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_2=floor(runif(5, min=11, max=100)),
                          ID_Station_3=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_3=floor(runif(5, min=101, max=200)))
Dist_Temp_Min<-data.frame(ID_School=seq(1:5),ID_Station_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),
                          ID_Station_2=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_2=floor(runif(5, min=11, max=100)),
                          ID_Station_3=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_3=floor(runif(5, min=101, max=200)))
Dist_Prec<-data.frame(ID_School=seq(1:5),ID_Station_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_1=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),
                      ID_Station_2=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_2=floor(runif(5, min=11, max=100)),
                      ID_Station_3=floor(runif(5, min=0, max=10)),Dist_3=floor(runif(5, min=101, max=200)))

years<-seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"),as.Date("2015-02-28"),by="1 day")
Weather_Data<-data.frame(ID_School=seq(1:5))
Weather_Data<-expand.grid(Weather_Data$ID_School,years)
names(Weather_Data)<-c("ID_Station","Date")
Weather_Data$Temp_Max_T<-runif(nrow(Weather_Data), min=10, max=40)
Weather_Data$Temp_Min_T<-Weather_Data$Temp_Max-10
Weather_Data$Prec_T<-floor(runif(nrow(Weather_Data),min=0, max=10))
Weather_Data$Cod_Merge<-paste(Weather_Data$ID_Station,Weather_Data$Date,sep="-")

#Add Values per Station
var_list<-c("Temp_Max","Temp_Min","Prec")
for (i in var_list) {
  dist<-paste0("Dist_",i)
  dist<-get(dist)
  dist<-as.data.frame(subset(dist,!is.na(dist$ID_Station_1)))
  matr<-dist[c("ID_School","ID_Station_1","Dist_1")]
  matr<-setDT(matr)[, list(Date=years,ID_Station_1=ID_Station_1,Dist_1=Dist_1) , ID_School]
 
  matr$Cod_Merge<-paste(matr$ID_Station_1,matr$Date,sep="-")
  matr<-as.data.frame(matr[,c("Cod_Merge","ID_School","Date","ID_Station_1","Dist_1")])
  matr<-merge(matr,Weather_Data[c("Cod_Merge",paste0(i,"_T"))],by="Cod_Merge",all.x=T)
  matr$Cod_Merge<-paste(matr$ID_School,matr$Date,sep="-")
  names(matr)[6]<-paste0(i,"_T_1")
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  print(i)
 
  for(n in 2:3) {
    matr2<-dist[c("ID_School",paste0("ID_Station_",n),paste0("Dist_",n))]
    matr2<-subset(dist,!is.na(dist[paste0("ID_Station_",n)]))
    matr3<-expand.grid(matr2$ID_School,years)

    names(matr3)<-c("ID_School","Date")
    matr3<-matr3[order(matr3$ID_School,matr3$Date), ]
    matr2<-merge(matr3,matr2,by="ID_School")
    rm(matr3)
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    print(i)
    
    matr2$Cod_Merge<-paste(matr2[,paste0("ID_Station_",n)],matr2$Date,sep="-")
    matr2<-matr2[,c("Cod_Merge","ID_School","Date",paste0("ID_Station_",n),paste0("Dist_",n))]
    matr2<-merge(matr2,Weather_Data[,c("Cod_Merge",paste0(i,"_T"))],by="Cod_Merge",all.x=T)
    matr2$Cod_Merge<-paste(matr2$ID_School,matr2$Date,sep="-")
    
    names(matr2)[6]<-paste0(i,"_T_",n)
    matr<-merge(matr,matr2[,c("Cod_Merge",
                              paste0("ID_Station_",n),
                              paste0("Dist_",n),
                              paste0(i,"_T_",n))],
                by="Cod_Merge",all.x=T)
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    print(i)
  }
  assign(paste0("Mat_Dist_",i),matr)
}
```

Comment: I'm not really able to follow this since there seems to be a lot going on. Can you simplify? Your code seems rather hard to understand. Can you provide a minimal example for someone to be able to run your code?

Comment: You don't need to recreate the 17 million rows for the example data... looking at it now. You actually receive the weather data frames in the wide format and separated?

Comment: Yes, they are in a wide format. It is a simple task however when I transferred my code into a loop I ran out of memory.

Comment: I am trying to help you rewrite your process but to do so I need to understand what you are doing. You are telling me you are running out of memory doing it this way. It seems to me that you shouldn't be merging so many rows and that there is a better way. I can't help you get there if you don't tell me, "I start with these 3 data frames. COD means this. For every day, for every school, i need to put the weather information next to it for the top 10 stations" --- I don't know how to help when I can't understand your desired result

Comment: Your expand.grid function is the root of the error. I'm trying to figre out why you are using it at all

Comment: That is exactly it. I need to merge the school-day panel with the weather_data panel. And repeat the process with the 10 closest stations. The final product needs to be that panel at the school-day level with the weather data for the 10 closest measurements.

Comment: I expand it because I dont know what dates have missing weather data, by doing so I make sure that everything merges.

Comment: I understand now, I've been creating better example data to test and the merge is not working. I believe the solution will be to perform this on smaller ranges of dates, such as 6 month intervals. Can I ask what is the end goal of this? A single file of 5 years of daily data will be quite large. May have to dive into https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: The end goal here is to create a panel of schools with the average max and min temp. per day. The issue, as in most weather datasets, is that there are many missing daily readings. Therefore, instead of just assigning the reading of the closest station, I am getting the average of the 10 closest stations within a 20 mile radius. That way i'm "filling" in readings that would have been missing otherwise. Anyway, I was able to get it to work. The issue was on a missing comma when creating a variable inside the loop. I'll post the correct one.

Comment: Ah okay, I rewrote it with simpler code but also faced the issue of many millions of rows. INow that I know what you're doing, I would do this one day at a time, and use inverse distance weighted averaging for the measurements. I'll post my code too.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I am doing. Which is why I need to keep the distance in the final dataframe to be able to estimate it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It might be worth using `fuzzyjoin::distance_left_join` to more efficiently collect nearby schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all your code would need to do is find the 10 closest stations to each school, and then you simply subset the station data to the school (don't know anything about your dates).

Your final data frame should be way better and easier to use -- probably instead of 3 separate wide data frames it should look like this:

```
set.seed(1)  # FAKE DATA
final <- data.frame(ID_School = rep(LETTERS[1],10), ID_Station = sample(1:100,10), 
                   Closeness_Rank = 1:10, Distance = 10*(1:10) + sample(-5:5,10), 
                   Temp.Max = sample(70:100,10), Temp.Min = sample(30:69,10), 
                   Precipitation = sample(20:30,10)/100)
final
#   ID_School ID_Station Closeness_Rank Distance Temp.Max Temp.Min Precipitation
#1          A         27              1        7       98       49          0.29
#2          A         37              2       16       76       53          0.26
#3          A         57              3       31       88       48          0.27
#4          A         89              4       38       73       36          0.24
#5          A         20              5       50       77       59          0.23
#6          A         86              6       65       80       68          0.28
#7          A         97              7       72       70       57          0.20
#8          A         62              8       79       79       33          0.21
#9          A         58              9       94       90       64          0.22
#10         A          6             10      103       96       42          0.30
```

Without knowing how you measure your distances for the station and school data or other information, I can't help you get to this format but if you provide more information I would be happy to help.

EDIT:

This method seems to be very slow as I'm not really using data.tables correctly but hopefully it should give you some ideas. I've generated the fake data in a way that might be useful for you for explaining your question in the future. My method is to only build the FINAL output, a day-school data.table of weather data derived from averaging the closest 10 stations that have data weighted by inverse distance.

The process is super slow, at ~ 7800 school weather's calculated in 5 minutes for a single day... so 6 and half days to complete for 5 years -- but no memory issues! This is the kind of code you would post and ask if someone can improve the speed.

```
# Starting from the beginning
set.seed(100)
library(data.table)

n_station <- 800
n_school <- 7800
station_info <- data.frame(ID_Station = 1:n_station, 
           xcoord = sample(-10000:10000,n_station), 
           ycoord = sample(-10000:10000,n_station))

school_info <- data.frame(ID_School = 1:n_school, 
           xcoord = sample(-10000:10000,n_school), 
           ycoord = sample(-10000:10000,n_school))

# save list of ~20 closest stations by school, 
# and always use 10 of the closest where measurements are available
x <- 20 
L <- vector('list', nrow(school_info)) # always initialize for speed
for(i in 1:nrow(school_info)){
    distances <- sqrt((school_info[i,"xcoord"] - station_info[,"xcoord"])^2 + 
                      (school_info[i,"ycoord"] - station_info[,"ycoord"])^2)
    L[[i]] <- cbind.data.frame(ID_School = rep(school_info[i,"ID_School"],x),
                               ID_Station = station_info[ which(order(distances) <= x), 
                                                         "ID_Station"],
                               Distance_Rank = 1:x,
                               Distance = sort(distances)[1:x])
}
L[[1]]
#        ID_School ID_Station Distance_Rank  Distance
# 1:         1          2             1  127.2242
# 2:         1         32             2  365.7896
# 3:         1         92             3  573.0428
# 4:         1        141             4  763.5837
# 5:         1        151             5 1003.4127
```

For 5 years of daily Fake Weather Data:

```
days <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"),as.Date("2015-12-31"),by="1 day")
d <- length(days)
S <- vector('list', nrow(station_info))
for(i in 1:nrow(station_info)){
  S[[i]] <- data.frame(ID_Station = rep(station_info[i,"ID_Station"],d),
                       Temp.Max = sample(70:100,d,T),
                       Temp.Min = sample(30:69,d,T), 
                       Precipitation = sample(20:30,d,T)/100,
                       date = days)
  # maybe remove some dates at random
  if(sample(c(T,F),1)) S[[i]] <- S[[i]][-sample(1:d,1),]
}
station_data <- as.data.table(do.call(rbind,S))
station_data
#        ID_Station Temp.Max Temp.Min Precipitation       date
#     1:          1       88       55          0.23 2010-01-01
#     2:          1       73       57          0.24 2010-01-02
#     3:          1       93       33          0.29 2010-01-03
#     4:          1       81       52          0.27 2010-01-04
#     5:          1       82       48          0.24 2010-01-05
#    ---                                                      
#291610:        800       86       31          0.28 2010-12-27
#291611:        800       98       57          0.22 2010-12-28
#291612:        800       71       50          0.26 2010-12-29
#291613:        800       83       35          0.26 2010-12-30
#291614:        800       71       34          0.23 2010-12-31
```

The algorithm:

```
size <- length(days) * n_school
#OUT <- data.table(ID_School = integer(size),
#                  date = as.Date(x = integer(size), origin = "1970-01-01"),
#                  wtd_Temp.Max= numeric(size),
#                  wtd_Temp.Min= numeric(size),
#                  wtd_Precip= numeric(size))
OUT <- vector('list',size) # faster

unique_school <- unique(school_data$ID_School) # will be length(n_school)
#length(L) is the same as length(unique(school)= n_school)

count = 0
for(i in 1:length(days)){
  t1 <- Sys.time()
  temp_weather_data = station_data[date==days[i],]
  m <- merge(school_data, temp_weather_data, "ID_Station")
setkey(m, ID_School) # the key is ID_School
  for(j in 1:length(unique_school)){
    count = count + 1
    # assuming within the closest 20 stations, at least 10 have data every day
    r <- m[.(j),][1:10] # find schools j in key
    invd <- 1/r$Distance
    sum.invd <- sum(invd)
    OUT[[count]] <- data.table(ID_School = unique_school[j], 
                               date = days[i], 
                               wtd_Temp.Max = sum(invd * r$Temp.Max)/sum.invd,
                               wtd_Temp.Min = sum(invd * r$Temp.Min)/sum.invd,
                               wtd_Precip = sum(invd * r$Precipitation)/sum.invd)
  if(j %% 100 == 0) cat(as.character(days[i]),".....",unique_school[j],"...\n")
  }
  cat(Sys.time()-t1)
}
```

Which gives the final output:

```
do.call(rbind,OUT)
#    ID_School       date wtd_Temp.Max wtd_Temp.Min wtd_Precip
# 1:         1 2010-01-01     88.64974     44.07872  0.2757571
# 2:         2 2010-01-01     83.34549     46.80225  0.2511073
# 3:         3 2010-01-01     85.32834     48.62004  0.2347837
# 4:         4 2010-01-01     82.95667     48.01814  0.2576482
# 5:         5 2010-01-01     87.88982     44.45357  0.2527794
# ---
```

Comment: The dates are from 2010-2015. And yes, you are correct. That is pretty much what I am trying to do. I already estimate the distance from each school to each station using the geosphere package. I'm trying to simplify the code further.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the dataframes? I only see the weather_data dataframe?

Comment: I've adding a key in which makes it marginally faster. Still learning how to use data.table so there is definitely room for improvement.

Comment: WAY faster to add it to a list, about 6.6 hours to complete a year of daily results

Comment: However, the do.call(rbind, OUT) at the end did crash my memory... Sorry I coudn't help more